# Prove/disprove function is a first integral of system of differential equations

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

To model an infectious disease, we look at the following epidemiological sizes:

S: "susceptible" - Amount of susceptible persons

I: "infectious" - Amount of infected persons

R: "recovered" - Amount of recovered persons

The chronological course of spread for $t \geq 0$ can be modeled via the following system of differential equations ([Kermack-McKendrick model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kermack%E2%80%93McKendrick_theory)):

$$\text{(1) }  \frac{dS}{dt} = - \lambda IS$$
$$\text{(2) }  \frac{dI}{dt} = \lambda IS - \gamma I$$
$$\text{(3) }  \frac{dR}{dt} = \gamma I$$

where $\lambda, \gamma > 0$ are model parameters.

$t=0$ marks the beginning of the spread and there are the  following initial conditions:

$$S(0)= S_0 > 0, I(0) = I_0 > 0, R(0) = R_0 \geq 0$$

I want to know how one can find out if the function $N = S+I+R$ is a first integral of $(1)-(3)$?

Basically, it's asking if a function where we have all the susceptible, infectious and recovered persons is a first integral of $\frac{dS}{dt} - \frac{dR}{dt}$

But how does one go on about this?

Comment: Is everything alright with the sign of $\lambda I S$ in the second ODE?

Comment: @Snoop Thanks for pointing that out. Sorry, it was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By taking the time derivative of $N(t,(S,I,R))=S(t)+I(t)+R(t)$ we obtain

$$\frac{d N}{dt}= \frac{d S}{dt }+ \frac{d I}{dt } + \frac{d R}{dt }=$$
$$=(-\lambda IS)+(\lambda IS-\gamma I)+(\gamma I)=0$$

So $N$ is a constant along any solution of the system, and it is therefore a first integral of the system. In fact, $N$ is the total population, which does not change in the model.